# 301 редирект только каталога

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

На сайте есть категория `www.site/category/`, а в ней находятся страницы типа `www.site/category/tv.html`, `www.site/category/phone.html` и т.д. Как сделать редирект категории  `www.site/category/` на `www.site/category.html`, но что бы страницы нормально работали.
Я поставил редирект `Redirect permanent /category/ https://www.site.com/category.html`, но страницы получились `https://www.site.com/category.htmlphone.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение:
`RewriteRule ^category/$ https://www.site.com/category.html [R=301,L]`
Редиректит категорию на .html, а если зайти на страницу то ссылка отображается правильно.